# Chrome Extension: chrome.tabs.executeScript not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm writing a chrome extension, and want to execute a content script from my background script. The background script executes, but the content doesn't. Here are the relevant chunks of code:

`manifest.json`:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/app/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
},

"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "*://*/*"
]
```

`background.js`:

```
console.log('background')
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content.js"})
```

`content.js`:

```
console.log('content')
```

When I inspect element, the console has `background` logged on it, but not `content`. The regular console also has nothing logged on it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've got to check in **the console of the tab**, not in the console of the background page.

Comment: nothing shows up there either.

Comment: Why dont you set tabId? In what tab content script should be executed?

Answer (score 4):

In your `background.js` wrap your `chrome.tabs.executeScript` in this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tab) {

    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: '/scripts/runsOnPageLoad.js'
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't get programmatic injection to work, so I have just specified it in the `content_scripts` field in manifest.json (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration)

Comment: This is indeed the correct way of declaring content scripts that should run on all pages that match a certain URL.

Answer (score 0):

you should add permision "activeTab". more information https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi

Answer (score 0):

It must be as mentioned below:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code:"alert('Any Javascript code comes here !');"
    });
```

});

**Note:** can execute in background script, Don't forgot to allow necessary permissions in manifest.json